# How can i change modal transparency in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, transparency, modal-dialog, modalpopups

I create a modal window with PopUpManager

```
_zoomImgPopUp = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, Image, true) as Image;
```

When the modal window is opened, all background is gray and with blur.
How can i change color, blur and transparency of background.

I find this article 
http://mprami.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/alert_popup_modal_transparancy_color_blur_changes/

but it is for "mx" application. I need something with "spark" components.

UPD: Solved. It must be:

```
_zoomImgPopUp.setStyle("modalTransparency", 0);
_zoomImgPopUp.setStyle("modalTransparencyBlur", 0);
PopUpManager.addPopUp(_zoomImgPopUp, this, true);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have access to styles in the  tag that affect Modal.

You should be able to do this:

```
_zoomImgPopUp.setStyle("modalTransparency",1);
_zoomImgPopUp.setStyle("modalTransparencyBlur",3);
_zoomImgPopUp.setStyle("modalTransparencyColor", #ff0000);
```

You can put this in your application / component / module that references the popup.

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace s library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark;
        @namespace mx library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo;
        global {
            modal-transparency: 1;
            modal-transparency-blur: 2;
            modal-transparency-color: #ff0000;
        }
</fx:Style>
```